# What sets the parameter for this constructor in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been learning about how dependency injection in MVC works. Im understanding that by configuring services in my Startup.cs, I can provide and Interface and pair that with an implementation so that it can "point" to the implementation I want to use during startup. However there's a second link in this chain and I don't quite understand how my "NullMailService" object is properly created since I never provide an argument and I don't see where and how it gets one.

Here I have my initial service config that points to the implementation of IMailService that I want to use

[image]

I know that this gets injected into my controller constructor here:

[image]

I know that this than triggeres the creation of my NullMailService here:

[image]

However what I don't understand is how and where my NullMailService constructor gets its argument??

Comment: This is also done using DI [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: So you're asking what's injecting the logger? The default web host builder uses a default logging implementation, basically. Btw, please post code in questions as *text* rather than screenshots.

Comment: It gets registered courtesy of `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`, in `Program.cs`. Here's the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/src/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L43) that shows the registration, for interest.